# C# - Get X percent of Y dynamically

Tags: c#

I've trying to calculate what is X% of Y, although I'm getting mixed results.

I've tried the following equations:

```
return (percent / i) * 100; // Gives 0 for 200.GetPercent(10)
return percent * 100 / i; // Gives 5 for 200.GetPercent(10)
```

For method:

```
public static int GetPercent(this int i, int percent)
{
    return percent * 100 / i;
}
```

But none are giving me 20 back for `200.GetPercent(10)`

Comment: Hint: if the X goes up *or* Y goes up, the result should go up, right? So you shouldn't be *dividing* by either of them. This isn't really a coding problem - it's just maths. Once you've worked out the maths, the code will be quite straightforward, with the one tricky aspect being that you're working with integer arithmetic.

Comment: `return (i * percent) / 100;`

Comment: Right, so have you tried it? Does it do what you want? What do you want to happen for something like "15% of 10"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct equation: Y * X / 100

```
public static int GetPercent(this int i, int percent)
{
    return (i * percent) / 100;
}
```

Comment: The maths is now correct, but are you sure you want to return an integer? With your current code, 3.GetPercent(50) will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are better dealt with using a a floating point type, here is a version using double with another parameter to set precision

```cs
public static double GetPercent(this int i, double percent, int precision) => 
    Math.Round(((i * percent) / 100), precision);
```

You can also define precision as an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments), to give it a default value with `int precision = n` (n being an int of your choice)

```cs
public static double GetPercent(this int i, double percent, int precision = 2) => 
    Math.Round(((i * percent) / 100), precision);

200.GetPercent(10, 4); //precision = 4
200.GetPercent(10); //precision defaults to = 2
```

Comment: `Math.Round` is useless here, since all operands are integers, you're doing integer math. Also, makes no sense returning double for this case. Best thig to do would be accept doubles or cast to double before doing the calculations.